# How do I troubleshoot routes in Laravel 3? (using the scaffold bundle)

Tags: php, laravel, scaffolding, laravel-3

Just starting with Laravel.

I've installed it on my wamp server and setup a virtual host in apache. The standard home controller works fine. I've installed the scaffold bundle and generated a blog according to the description at the bundle's [github page](https://github.com/loic-sharma/scaffold). There was no errors.

I've added `Route::controller(Controller::detect());` to my routes.php but none seem to be working. I've tried http://laravel.dev/blog/posts/create and http://laravel.dev/blog/post/create. The scaffold created 3 controllers, users.php, blog/posts.php and blog/comments.php.

laravel.dev is a virtual host pointing with D:\wamp\www\laravel\public as DocumentRoot.

What are the possible issues? Where do I start looking?

Answer (score 0):

Dont use `Route::controller(Controller::detect())` - its known to be buggy and causes alot of issue.

Just define each controller individually in the routes.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you might have to include "index.php" (http://laravel.dev/index.php/blog/posts/create) in your URLs for it to work. This is a default option set in Laravel.

If you would like to turn this off for cleaner URLs, set "index" to an empty string in config/application.php.

You can read more about this in the documentation: http://laravel.com/docs/install#cleaner-urls